# Identificar correspondência em dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe d1.

```
Ano/Mês Referência  Ano/Mês Competência UF  Código Município SIAFI  Nome Município SIAFI    NIS Beneficiário    Nome Beneficiário   Valor Benefício
0   201301  201202  AL  2785    MACEIO  16035155015 ADRIANA MACEDO BALBINO  102,00
1   201301  201202  AL  2785    MACEIO  16411759287 LENILDA NAZARENA DE OLIVEIRA    70,00
```

Dataframe d2.

```
Ano/Mês Referência  Ano/Mês Competência UF  Código Município SIAFI  Nome Município SIAFI    NIS Beneficiário    Nome Beneficiário   Valor Benefício
0   202001  201202  AL  2785    MACEIO  16035155015 ADRIANA MACEDO BALBINO  200,00
1   202001  201202  AL  2785    MACEIO  12347759287 MARCELO PEREIRA DE OLIVEIRA 340,00
```

Preciso identificar os valores que se repetem nos dois dataframes na coluna 'NIS Beneficiário'.

Crio outra coluna? Como fazer a correspondência?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer encontrar intercessões entre os valores de duas colunas de dois `dataframes` distintos.

Para achar intercessões você pode converter as colunas que queira encontrar intercessões em [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Em Python conjuntos são coleções não ordenadas e sem elementos duplicados e são representados pela classe [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

As intercessões podem ser encontradas com o método [`intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

Para facilitar no exemplo calculei as intercessões nas colunas `age` de dois `dataframes` que [encontrei na internet](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_examples/):

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])


raw_data_2 = {'first_name': ['Sarah', 'Gueniva', 'Know', 'Sara', 'Cat'], 
        'last_name': ['Mornig', 'Jaker', 'Alom', 'Ormon', 'Koozer'], 
        'age': [53, 26, 72, 73, 24], 
        'preTestScore': [13, 52, 72, 26, 26],
        'postTestScore': [82, 52, 56, 234, 254]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_2, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

intercessão = set(df1['age']).intersection(set(df2['age']))

print(intercessão)

# {24, 73}
```

Exemplo no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/MutedJuicyTraining

No seu caso supondo que `d1` e `d2` sejam seus `dataframes` e que `NIS Beneficiário` seja o nome das colunas em questão, ficaria assim:

```
intercessão = set(d1['NIS Beneficiário']).intersection(set(d2['NIS Beneficiário']))
```

Comment: Obrigado. Mas eu preciso ver em quais linhas há a interseção. Vou precisar de consultar nome, município e estado. O ideal seria que os resultados aparecessem num terceiro dataframe.

Comment: @vivape isso de identificar as linhas não estava discriminado na pergunta.